# Informatica Administrator: Domain site refuse to connect

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have successfully completed the installation of informatica, and I am able to login domain Administrator http://ssingh:6008/administrator but the session get timed out after some time of inactivity.
The issue I am facing is It shows error to reconnect i.e. **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. Although this issue does not occur everytime, but frequently seen this issue. 
Thanks in advance for the solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It requires informatica service to be up and running. So go to System services and Start Informatica service. Wait for few minutes once service get started, and then will be able to view Administrator page.
P.S. I got this answer after self experimenting it. If any one knows better answer please do post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and as you suggested, all what we need to do is to check if the service is running under Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services (for Windows users) and be patient. My browser connects to the tool automatically after 3 or 4 minutes. Thank you!